# Awk outputting '00' instead of proper format

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to print output to an HTML file from another file using bash. The file I am trying to extract from looks like this:

```
192.168.1.42    42.8G    45.1G
192.168.1.47    47.2G    35.8G
```

What I am trying to do is write it to a table with a "More Info" button which will be a link. Here is the "awk" command I am trying to use:

```
awk '{print "      <tr><td>"$1"</td><td>"$2"</td><td>"$3"</td><td><a href=#"$1"><button class="'"btn btn-primary btn-sm"'">More Info</button></a></td></tr>"}'
```

Output to the HTML document I am looking for is:

```
<tr><td>192.168.1.42</td><td>42.8G</td><td>45.1G</td><td><a href=#192.168.1.42><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">More Info</button></a></td></tr>
```

The main issue is the "Button" class

Is there anyway I can do this or a better way in bash to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting `00` because it is the result of `btn-primary` and `btn-sm`. You probably want to escape the `"` so that the text gets printed properly:

```
<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\">More Info</button>
              ^                       ^
```

Your current

```
<button class="'"btn btn-primary btn-sm"'">More Info</button>
```

tries to use the variables `btn`, `primary` and `sm`, which are not defined, and prints the result of `btn - primary` and `btn - sm`, which is `0` as per variables not defined.

See more generally how `awk` behaves when operating on undefined variables:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print a-b}'
0
```

Finally, `printf` could help you handling values in a better way:

```
awk '{printf "<tr><td>%d</td><td>%d</td></tr>\n", $1, $2}' file
```

Comment: It looks like the escape characters worked. I tried using them before but was using them in the wrong places. I'm kicking myself in the butt for that one. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem, these nested single and double quotes get quite messy sometimes. Glad that it worked to you.

Comment: And they can be very dependent on your choice of shell. Read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html and then its just easier to do \47 for single quotes!